Can we have Pgpool-II and PostgreSQL on a same server? any challenges if we have a synchronous streaming replication set up with postgres cluster
Can we have Pgpool-II and PostgreSQL on a same server? any challenges if we have a synchronous streaming replication set up with postgres cluster.
Postgres version 15
pgpool-II version 4.2

You can, and it somewhat simplifies syncing them up at the obvious cost of having to manage multiple things on one box.
On its own pgPool-II doesn't make synchronous streaming replication challenging any more than it already is (if at all) - I think it's the usual pick for load balancing the pool offers. If anything, balancing makes it less challenging, with the queries being more evenly distributed between your active nodes.
You might get some more insight at dba or superuser sites.
